# Is there a way to loop through different levels of a factor for anomaly detection

Tags: r, loops, time-series, anomaly-detection

I am using the 'anomalize' package for anomaly detection. My data consists of three columns, the date, an agent (this is where the different levels come from), and the number of schedules that agent had on a particular day. I can run the anomaly detection just fine when I remove the 'agent' column and sum the number of consults by day using this code:

```
df <- scheds %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  summarise(
    new_scheds = sum(new_scheds)
  )
df_ts <- df %>% rownames_to_column() %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) %>% select(-one_of('rowname'))

df_ts <- df_ts[order(df_ts$date),]
########## TS Decomp ###############
   df_ts %>% 
  time_decompose(new_scheds, method = "stl", frequency = 5, trend = "auto") %>%
  anomalize(remainder, method = "gesd", alpha = 0.05, max_anoms = 0.2) %>%
  plot_anomaly_decomposition()
```

But I cannot find out how I would do this same type of thing for each agent individually without manually typing everything out and using filter(). I have tried the following loop with no luck:

```
agents <- levels(ts_agents$agent)
results <- matrix(NA, length(agents))

for(i in 1:length(agents)){
  ts_agents %>% 
    time_decompose(new_scheds)[i] %>%
    anomalize(remainder)[i] %>%
    time_recompose()[i] %>%
    plot_anomalies(time_recomposed = TRUE, ncol = 3, alpha_dots = 0.5)[i] }
```

but I get the following error:
'Error in time_decompose(new_scheds) : object 'new_scheds' not found'
Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that the pipe operator `%>%` doesn't work right when you try to subset your data.

If you enclose it in brackets and use `.` to refer to the input, you will avoid this error:

```r
for(i in 1:length(agents)){
  ts_agents %>% { 
    time_decompose(., new_scheds)[i]
  } %>% {
    ...
```

This fixes the immediate problem of the error but I'm not sure how well the subsetting will work. It may be that you need `filter()` in the loop, or even `group_by(df, agent)` without any loop at all. (If you provide a full reproducible example including data, it will be easier to help).